# Calculated fields in SQL SELECT statment

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand better how select statement calculated fields work. What I'm attempting to do is calculate video completion rate or VCR, this is calculated by completes/impressions. So I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT completes, impressions, completes/impression AS VCR
FROM video_table
WHERE (completes > 0)
```

The issue I run into is that for some reason there are videos that for whatever reason have 0 completes and lets say 25,000 impressions. On an individual level my calculation works fine but when you begin wrapping all these video up into say a website the VCR drops alot because of these 0 complete placement level video but they still have impressions. I'm wondering how do I deal with those 0 complete video placements even when I calculate the VCR for an entire website that consists of say 50 video placements of which 10 have 0 completes and 25,000 impressions?

Thanks anyone for ideas

***EDIT***

Simple example is:

```
Completes
1. 0
2. 7

Impressions
1. 10
2. 10

total VCR should equal 7/10 = 70%  **NOT**  7/20 = 35%
```

Comment: Can you maybe expand upon the problem? It sounds like the 0 completes (completed viewing?) are being taken into account in your calculation, which I would assume you want for accurate representation of the data? These videos with no completes are still real in the data, right?

Comment: Maybe show a few lines of sample data, its output, and the desired output?

Comment: Are you actually asking about how to do something using code, or are you just asking for a suggestion about what algorithm to use?

Comment: yeah i would like a piece of code if possible. The 0 video completes are not real placements, they are actually running but the ad server still tracks impression, they are ghost impressions.

Comment: it wont let me upload a picture or create an html table so i'm kinda stuck here

Comment: Based on your example, the query you provide should produce the right answer.

Comment: how do you add grand total calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You could use logic [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), but I think just better and faster to use to separate statements.

`SELECT completes, impressions, completes/impression AS VCR FROM video_table WHERE completes > 0 AND impression > 0` and than second select for all ones that have impressions equal to 0.

You can also always do the math in data transformation in language that you are programming. for example php. in this case you can just use simple logic there.

I hope this is what you were looking for.